# how do take last value from one property in JSON in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

so I have chatting application, with this JSON:

```
{
    "561c": [{
        "from": "561c",
        "fromname": "ryan",
        "to": "sasa",
        "messgae": "hey"
    }, {
        "from": "5512",
        "fromname": "sasa",
        "to": "ryan",
        "messgae": "hey too"
    }]
}
```

but this JSON will always add up when the users send messages. I want to take the **the last** value just from **"message"** to use this value in my Text-to-Speech code, how do I write the code?

and this is my Text-to-Speech:

```
$scope.speakText = function() {
    TTS.speak({
           text: ***this place is for the code***,
           locale: 'en-GB',
           rate: 0.75
       }, function () {
           // handle the succes case
       }, function (reason) {
           // Handle the error case
       });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

use forEach loop on the object '561c' like

```
   var messArray = [];
    561c.forEach(function(obj){

    messArray.push(obj.message)})

var text = messArray.join();
```

You will have all the message in messArray.
If i have understood your question correct.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I edited my question, not all value but just the last one, but this array will always add up when the users send messages again.

Answer (score 1):

//get the last element of array

```
var lastIndex = 561c.length();
var lastObj = 561c[lastIndex];
```

//get message from last object of array 561c

```
var lastMessage = lastObj.message;
```

and you got what you want(y);

Comment: actually my JSON is inside $scope.messageshistory, so can I change the 561c to $scope.messageshistory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "pluck" function of underscore.js - http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

_.pluck(**your array of JSONs**, 'messgae');

Comment: I'm so sorry, I edited my question, not all value but just the last one, but this array will always add up when the users send messages again.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $scope to your function then pass 561c you will get object then you can index message in it

Example :

```
$scope.chat =   {
"561c": [{
    "from": "561c",
    "fromname": "ryan",
    "to": "sasa",
    "messgae": "hey"
}, {
    "from": "5512",
    "fromname": "sasa",
    "to": "ryan",
    "messgae": "hey too"
}]
}

angular.module('app',[]).controller('myctrl', function($scope, data){
$scope.561c = data.messgae; 
 }
```

Comment: actually I done that, its in $scope.messageshistory, so in the last I just use `$scope.messageshistory = data.message` or still with 561c